# What should I store the content of text_area in a forms in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, string, textarea

Additionally if I want to store HTML in that text_area how can I render it as HTML?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking for. But the basics are:

Your text area should most likely be linked to a an attribute of type TEXT so you are not limited in the size. [See the migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for details.

As for storing straight HTML, it's dangerous to let user input arbitrary HTML content, specially if it's going to be seen by other user (for example on a forum) as it would allow anybody to add javascript to the page. This is also known as [XSS or Cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Think of at least of sanitizing the input.

To display the "raw" HTML content, in Rails 3 you need to add `.html_safe` to your attribute. This mean Rails will not clean it up and will render the content as is in the page.